# App version not displayed in App settings

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I am developing an iOS app in codova and the App **version** (eg. 0.2.1) is not displayed in the settings.

Only the permissions are displayed but the rest of the setting page is empty.

What am I missing? I can't find any info online.

Thanks

UPDATE:

What is missing is the Settings.bundle folders and files.

- How can I generate them using Cordova/PhoneGap/Ionic?

Comment: I should have specified. I am buildinding the iOS App using Cordova. I can use a plugin to get the app version but the version in the Settings of the App remains empty.

Comment: This plugin helps generate the Settings.bundle folder and files but it hasn't been maintained since 2017.. :( https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences